# Xcode Embedded navigation controller back-button not showing

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

I've just started learning Swift and Xcode, so I apologise in advance if my question is confusing or missing information. Please let me know if that's the case.

My question is on the automatic navigation bar created when I embed my scenes in the navigation controller.

As I've tried to show in my screenshot in the link below, my idea is to use the "Refusion" button in scene 1 to show scene 2. This works. However, scene 2 does not generate an automatic back button this way, which is what I'm trying to get.

If I create a button in scene 2 that shows scene 1 upon being pressed, scene 1 will now have an automatically generated back button. But this sends the user/me back from scene 1 to scene 2.. Which I already have my "Refusion" button for and also it just creates a confusing loop.

So, my question is: I'm trying to figure out how to get the auto-back button on my scene 2 and just scene 2, how do I do that? I'm probably doing something wrong, but would appreciate any help in where my error is.

I've embedded both scenes in the navigation controller.

Thanks,

https://ibb.co/jfZeSa

Comment: Just use PUSH Action Segue instead of SHOW . It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to embed only `scene 1` in `navigation controller`.
2. When you tap on `Refusion` button, **push** `scene 2`. `Scene` 2 then will be added in the `navigation stack`. In this case default `back button` will appear on the `navigation bar`.
3. In case you **present** `scene 2` from `scene 1`, `back button` won't appear on the `navigation bar`. i.e. `scene 2` won't be added in the `navigation stack`.
4. `Back button` on `navigation bar` only appear on the controllers that are the part of `navigation stack`.

[image]

Comment: Only embedding scene 1 did the trick for me, thank you! 

Now, on to the next challenge! :)